# NPM test error on ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs, ember-cli, travis-ci, ember-cli-addons

I was trying to test the app using npm test inside my ember application i ran through following error. How could i find which line has caused the error? Thanks in advance .

[image]

My system is ubuntu 14.0.4TLS

My node version is :

node -v : v0.12.7

ember -v : 1.13.1

npm: 2.12.1

phantomjs -v :1.9.0